# PHP installation missing while opening website

Tags: php, wordpress, mysql

All was working fine but then suddenly **Your PHP installation appears to be missing the MySQL extension which is required by WordPress** came when I try to my site.

Hosting:Godaddy
PHP version:5.4.26
MySQL version:5.5.36-cll-lve

Pleaes help as my site is down for more than a day andI am suffering earning loss

Comment: Sorry but the question is too specific and unlikely to help others, and the problem is likely out of your control, you should contact GoDaddy's support team.

Comment: You need to call GoDaddy tech support ASAP!

Comment: If you Google that specific error message you will get quite a few results and many of those seem to be related to GoDaddy Hosting, which date back 6+ years!? Just curious... are you on Windows hosting (seems to be a common element with those that have this problem - although TBH I can't see why that should be).